# strace EPERM for cloned subprocess

Tags: strace

I am trying to strace some binary but encounter on strange problem

```
strace -f ./ioncube_encoder53
```

it traces main process ok, but when trying to trace child subprocess it failed with

```
clone(Process 22790 attached
child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0xff4918) = 22790
[pid 22789] waitpid(22790, Process 22789 suspended
 <unfinished ...>
[pid 22790] ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, 0, 0, 0) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
```

below are details of my environment:

```
[root@alpaca-dev ioncube]# id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root),1(bin),2(daemon),3(sys),4(adm),6(disk),10(wheel)

[root@alpaca-dev ioncube]# getenforce
Disabled

[root@alpaca-dev ioncube]# cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS release 5.9 (Final)

[root@alpaca-dev ioncube]# uname -a
Linux alpaca-dev.lunarbreeze.com 2.6.18-348.4.1.el5xen #1 SMP Tue Apr 16 17:29:06 EDT 2013 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

I switched off selinux, tracing under 'root' user, tracing descendant process,
I don't find any mentions that process can forbid itself from tracing

any ideas ?

Comment: From what I understand, a process can remove the PTRACE capability from it's inherited set.  I don't know if this is the problem, I've a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see here: https://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2015/11/15/strace-cheat-sheet/, this can happen if "strace is not allowed to attach to processes on your system". Maybe it doesn't inherit some flags from the parent and sets them to some system defaults (wild guess).

You can follow the steps from the beginning of the article to disable that behaviour and allow all processed to be traced.

Hope it helps.